# How do I move cursor to the start on OS X

Tags: macos, fish

Using fish shell, how do I move to the beginning of the line on OS X with Apple keyboard (no <kbd>Home</kbd> button).

<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> does not work

Comment: LMGTFY: https://www.cheatography.com/myounkin/cheat-sheets/fish-shell/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From @kometen's comment:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> - Move to beginning of line
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> - Move to end of line

More here: https://www.cheatography.com/myounkin/cheat-sheets/fish-shell/

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you're using the default (emacs) key bindings or Vi key bindings. See the output of

`bind | grep beginning-of-line`

to learn what character sequences will move the cursor to the start of the line. The end of line equivalent should be obvious.

Also, unless you've configured your terminal emulator (Apple Terminal, iTerm2, or something else) to send a sequence of ASCII characters when you press [Fn]+[left-arrow] you won't be able to use that combination of keys. However, there is a good chance that your terminal emulator maps them to [Home] and [End] which should send the expected sequences of characters. For example, `\e[H` is commonly sent by the [Home] key and you should see that in the `bind` output.